# Fetch relation of fetched relation in hibernate HQL query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have entity Customer, Car:

```
@Entity
public class Customer{
  List<Car> cars;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Car{
  List<Customer> previousOwners;
  ...
}
```

Basicly Customer can have multiple cars rented, and Cars remember previous owners.

**Both entities have more relations, and i am omiting them.**

Now  want to retrieve all cars of Customer:

```
public List<Car> getCars(int customerId) {
    List<Car> cars= new ArrayList<>();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        cars= (List<Car>) session.createQuery("SELECT cars FROM Customer u JOIN  u.cars cars WHERE u.id IN :ids ").setParameter("ids", customerId).list();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cars;
}
```

This will return list of Cars, i need to use JOIN cuz lazyinitialization is set to FALSE.

Now i want to fetch Cars and their previos owners. But i am unable to think of any query, i tried using:

`"SELECT cars FROM Customer u JOIN  u.cars cars JOIN u.cars.previousOwners previousOwners WHERE u.id IN :ids "` but this did nothing.

What i am aming for is to return **object Car, with list inside**, when i tried using

```
"SELECT cars, cars.previousOwner FROM Customer u JOIN  u.cars cars JOIN u.cars.previousOwner previosOwner WHERE u.id IN :ids "
```

it returned the list of previousOwners, but not inside Car object, but as second element in returned list...

How can i create such query? Thanks fo help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a (`LEFT`) `JOIN FETCH` query:

```
SELECT cars FROM Customer u
JOIN u.cars cars
JOIN FETCH cars.previousOwners
WHERE u.id IN :ids
```

This instructs Hibernate to join the cars.previousOwners relation even when it's declared to use lazy-fetching by default. Use a left join fetch if you also want to return cars with no previousOwners.

See the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join) for more info.